# How to write an autohotkey script to toggle the Show hidden files and folders setting?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I would like to make use of a hotkey to toggle the Show hidden files and folders setting. 
I want to use it on both windowsXp and Windows7.

Here is what I got so far:

```
#h::
RegRead, Showall_Status, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL, CheckedValue, 
If Showall_Status = 0
RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL, CheckedValue, 1 
Else
RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL, CheckedValue, 0
Return
```

Problem is when I run the script it simply does nothing. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Do you want to toggle the **Show hidden files and folders** setting, or toggle the hidden bit of a file/folder?

Comment: I want to toggle the Show hidden files and folders setting.

Comment: does it require some kind of refresh to the folder view (like f5)?

Comment: Never hurts to include it in the script would it? Goo point though @Matthew

Comment: I suppose it does. I just tried adding- Send, {F5} - at the end. Yet it still just does nothing. I am on WinXP at the moment.

Comment: Usually when you make a change in the registry like that you have to terminate and restart explorer.exe and it will re-read the registry values.  Perhaps there is some way to send a signal to explorer to get it to re-read?

Comment: See (http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=20695)

Comment: I use StExBar for quickly toggling hidden/not hidden status: http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/StExBar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the regkey, this one works.

```
;------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Show hidden folders and files in Windows XP
;------------------------------------------------------------------------
; User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
; Value Name: Hidden
; Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
; Value Data: (1 = show hidden, 2 = do not show)

    #h::

        RegRead, ShowHidden_Status, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden
        if ShowHidden_Status = 2 
        RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden, 1
        Else
        RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden, 2
        WinGetClass, CabinetWClass
        PostMessage, 0x111, 28931,,, A
        Return
```

Comment: see below for win7...

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough points to reply, so I'm posting this as another answer...

The explorer won't refresh with the above `PostMessage` in win7.  So you'll want both of these to work in XP and win7.

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic1204.html

```
PostMessage, 0x111, 28931,,, A
PostMessage, 0x111, 41504,,, A
```

Comment: thanks will test it. For Win7 I used "Send {F5}", and it worked. For XP I used "PostMessage, 0x111, 28931,,, A"