# Toggle Windows Explorer ascending/descending by hotkey?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

This [thread](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=64414) explains how you can bind a hotkey to various sort by options.

but I am specifically looking for a way to toggle just the ascending/descending order without changing the ordering method such as "size"Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest approach, would be to trigger the right click menu, then type 'o', then type 'd'.

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/118570/how-to-write-an-autohotkey-script-to-toggle-the-show-hidden-files-and-folders-se?rq=1
it would be nice if we could follow this approach, but a similar setting is not exposed via registry. 
https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-reghacks.html

Comment: I was thinking of a way of getting AHK to automate this, it proved to be difficult, mainly due to Explorer window position and size being random. So getting the cursor on an area of explorer that is empty proved to be difficult.  but if you press alt  you can expose Explorers menu bar from there on its your solution. Thank you!